# Como obtenga la suma de las cifras de un numero en javaSript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando obtener la suma de las cifras de varios números y comparalos para saber si su suma da 12, aquí un ejemplo: 124 sería 1 + 2 + 4 = 7 , 426 sería 4 + 2 + 6 = 12.

Lo que no logro es obtener los números de cada cifra, por lo que pregunto por aquí haber si alguien logra saber como resolver este problema.

Nota: esto debe ser hecho con javacript.
En cuanto a lo que intentando es usar la función char y eso pero no sirvió, igualmente les copio aquí el código(verán que sobra ponerlo).

```
<Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hola</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="Filas" /><br>
  <input type="text" id="Columnas" /><br>
  <button type="button" onClick="HacerArreglo()">Crear Tabla</button><br>
  <script>
    function HacerArreglo(){
      var Filas = parseInt(document.getElementById("Filas").value);
      var Columnas = parseInt(document.getElementById("Columnas").value);
      Arreglo = [];
      var Primos = 0;
      var Diez = 0;
      var Perfectos = 0;
      var Capicuas = 0;
      var contCap = 0;
      var posicion = 0;
      var terminaEnCu = 0;
      document.write(" <table border='2'>  ");
      for (i = 1; i <= Filas; i++){
        document.write(" <tr>  ");
        for(j = 1; j <= Columnas; j++){
          var aleatorio = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000));
          if (aleatorio < 100){
            aleatorio = aleatorio + 100;
          }
          document.write("<td>" + aleatorio + "</td>");
          Arreglo.push(aleatorio);
          var primo = 0;
          if((Arreglo[posicion].toString().split('').reverse().join('')) === Arreglo[posicion].toString()){
            Capicuas++;
            contCap = contCap + Arreglo[posicion];
          }
          if(Arreglo[posicion] == 496){
            Perfectos++;
          }
          for(n = 2; n <= Arreglo[i]/2;n++){
            if(aleatorio % n == 0){
              primo++;
            }
          }
          if(primo == 0){
            Primos++;
          }
          if(primo > 8){
            Diez++;
          }
          if(Arreglo[posicion] % 100 == 4){
            terminaEnCu++;
          }
          else{
            if((Arreglo[posicion] % 100) % 10 == 4){
              terminaEnCu++;
            }
          }
          posicion = posicion + 1;
        }
      }
      var PromedioCap = 0;
      PromedioCap = contCap/Capicuas;
      document.write(" </tr>  ");
      document.write(" </table>  ");
      document.write(". Cantidad de primos: "+Primos);
      document.write(". Cantidad de numeros con mas de diez divisores: "+Diez);
      document.write(". Cantidad de capicuas: "+Capicuas);
      document.write(". Cantidad de perfectos: "+Perfectos);
      document.write(". Cantidad de numeros que terminan en 4: "+terminaEnCu);
      document.write(". Promedio de capicuas: "+PromedioCap);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que has hecho? Edita y muestra

Answer (score 1):

Mediante el residuo del número dividido entre 10 puedes realizar la suma de los dígitos de un número:

- Siendo `numero = 52`
- Obtén el último dígito mediante el residuo `52 % 10 = 2`
- Suma el valor obtenido dentro del total `total += 2`
- Reemplaza `numero` por los dígitos que aún no se han sumado `numero =~~(52 / 10)` : `numero = 5`
- Realiza este proceso mientras que el `numero` sea mayor a `0`

```js
function sumarDigitos(numero) {
  let total = 0;
  while(numero > 0) {  
    total += (numero % 10);
    numero = ~~(numero / 10);    
  }
  
  return total;
}

console.log(sumarDigitos(52597));
console.log(5+2+5+9+7);
```

Comment: edita y explica por favor